# Get rid of rows with parts of strings

Tags: r, filter

I have a dataframe `individual_dets` that has a few rows that I want to get rid of

```
area                       year               Temp
BON-AR-S2                  2016               1.853
BON-W-S5                   2018               2.2
HFX 102                    2018               1.2
NSTR 525                   2017               2.0  
NSTR 787                   2017               2.3
HFX 101                    2016               1.9 
Boca Raton                 2015               20
Shutter                    2015               21
Shutter                    2017               1.3
Ketch                      2017               1.3
Ketch                      2018               1.9
```

I want to keep only the rows which have strings starting with NSTR, HFX, and Boca raton rows... how do I keep just these.... or how do I get rid of the rest. I've tried using multiples of this

```
individual_dets$area = filter(individual_dets, area != "BON-AR-S2")
```

But it outputs a completely different dataframe without my original data, I've also tried

```
individual_dets = filter(individual_dets, area != "BON-AR-S2")
```

but nothing happens...

anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`!=` and `==` only works on exact matches. If you want to match part of the string you need `grepl`. You also say the lines should start with NSTR, HFX, or Boca. Start of the line can be expressed with the regex `^`. For more than one pattern you can use `|` which is the regex for *or*:

```
individual_dets = filter(individual_dets, grepl("^NSTR|^HFX|^Boca", area))
```

Answer (score 0):

when searching for strings you don't use `==`, but rather `%in%`

if you want to return the data.frame without certain rows, you don't write `individual_dets$area =` but rather `df =`. The former would change a column in your table, the latter creates a new data.frame

you can use `subset` (base R) instead of `filter` (requires dplyr)

putting it all together:

```
df = subset(individual_dets, !area %in% "BON-AR-S2")
```

edit: as pointed out by @JBGruber, use `subset(individual_dets, !grepl("BON", area))` if you want to be more general in string-finding